# Autofilter table in one sheet for values greater than variable in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Basics --- File1 contains Table1 and File2 contains Table2.  My macro, contained in File2, copies rows from Table1 and pastes them to the bottom of Table2. Every time I run the macro, I record a timestamp in File2.

Specifics --- I want to copy from Table1 only those rows which contain a date (located in column 16) later than the timestamp I recorded in File2 the last time I ran the macro.

File1 is ComboFile; Table1 is ComboWeekTable; File2 is Rollup; Table2 is RollupWeekTable

```
Sub CopyToRollup()

Dim RollupWeekSheet As Worksheet
Set RollupWeekSheet = Workbooks("Tasks - Rollup").Sheets("Weekly")

Dim RollupWeekTable As ListObject
Set RollupWeekTable = RollupWeekSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

Dim RollupTimeStamp As String
RollupTimeStamp = RollupWeekSheet.Range("B3").Value



Dim ComboFile As Workbook
Set ComboFile = Workbooks.Open(ComboPath, ReadOnly:=True)
'Opens ComboFile as Read Only~~~~~~~~~~~

Dim ComboWeekSheet As Worksheet
Set ComboWeekSheet = ComboFile.Sheets("Weekly")

Dim ComboWeekTable As ListObject
Set ComboWeekTable = ComboWeekSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
'Define most variables~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Dim LastRollupWeekRow As Long
Dim sh1Col As Integer
With RollupWeekSheet
sh1Col = .Range("Table1").Cells(1).Column
LastRollupWeekRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sh1Col).End(xlUp).Row
End With
'Move to the next empty row in Rollup Table 1.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



With ComboWeekTable
.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">" & RollupTimeStamp
.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

With RollupWeekSheet
.Cells(LastRollupWeekRow + 1, sh1Col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
'Filter ComboWeekTable column 16 for values greater than RollupTimeStamp, copy from ComboWeekTable only those rows added later than the timestamp, and paste them to the bottom of RollupWeekTable.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



RollupWeekSheet.Range("B3").Value = DateTime.Now

ComboFile.Close savechanges:=False
'Record a new RollupTimeStamp and close ComboFile.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

End Sub
```

It keeps telling me that a "Named arguement not found" for my autofilter.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What line is the error happening at?

Comment: .Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria:=">" & RollupTimeStamp

Comment: This has nothing to with your problem, but you don't need `DateTime.Now` just use `Now`.

Comment: My previous comment (now deleted) wasnt useful. This website has a lot of useful tips on table ranges... good luck. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: I changed Criteria to Criteria1 and fixed my original problem (and edited code above to reflect this).  Now my problem is that I am pasting the filtered table's header (top) row.  How can I copy and past only the filtered data body range?